# Using greybox js library to show a window using the google tts

Tags: javascript, django, text-to-speech, google-translate

EDITED THIS FOR CLARITY:

I have a Django app!

I want to use the google tts stuff for translation of certain items on my web page. Now I have an onclick, yes I should know better, that calls a javascript function from a Django template, passing it a phrase, which the function does some work on, inserting commas for better pronounciation etc.

I pass the greybox the url and it opens no problem, Firefox, chrome...etc. place an embedded media player (gnome media player in this case) in the window so it obviously knows it is audio, however the sound doesn't play, which is odd as it played in another setup I had previously, with the same browsers without any code changes.

Here is the call to the greybox function from within my function:

```
return GB_showCenter(caption, "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=I hate programming, don't you?");
```

Now if you take the same url and put it straight into the browser address bar it will work. Also the same call will work from a NON DJANGO TEMPLATE, e.g. If I have the same tag with the same onlcik from a straight Html file, it works....

I am using Firefox 4 in Linux Mint, but it is the same in Opera 11.10 and Chrome.

Any ideas? Is it something to do with cache perhaps?

Thanks

p.s. I also tried it with the following but the same, doesn't play..

```
window.open(url,caption,'width=400,height=200,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=no,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=n0,copyhistory=no,resizable=0');
```

UPDATE: If I use the link in a normal browser window, and then I click the greybox link it works. I am assuming because the file is in cache...

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is flawed:

```
return GB_showCenter(caption, "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en?q=I hate programming, don't you?");
```

Should not have a question mark after "en", but an ampersand:

```
return GB_showCenter(caption, "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=I hate programming, don't you?");
```

And, no, I love programming.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry that is not how it is in my code, I hand typed that in as an example, I have the ampersand in there, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally, no solution to this problem using greybox. Did some experiments and found lightwindow to be a better option. However, it is a tad heavy and realies on prototype.js library and a coupel of other files, so I'm considering my options, and neat ways to minimise the clients upload burden visa ve javascript and all the increasingly extensive CSS stuff. But, for the purposes of prototyping this rather neat little speech module, lightwindow does the job. Also, I don't think grebox is currently being maintained, so it would be a question of pick the bones and re-write. This is something I would rather start from scratch if it is neccesary.